# ES6, React: If instance of class is exported, is it safe to assume that all imports will refer to it and that it will not be re-instatiated?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

Is it safe to export like this:

```
class Jwt {
    token: string;

    constructor() {
        this.token = '';
    }

    set(token: string) {
        this.token = token;
    }

    get() {
        return this.token;
    }
}

export const jwt = new Jwt();
```

... and to use the imported instance (`import { jwt } from 'helpers/jwt';`) in different files of the application, and to rely that it will be always the same instance? Also, is it reliable that it will not be garbage-collected and re-initialized on demand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is safe to rely on the instance of it.

There's always a way of accessing it (via the module system), so it can't be garbage collected.